# In search for a perfect dropdown menu: stretching to full width, equal width items, pure CSS. Please help resolve a glitch

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement a **menu** with the following features:

- horizontal;
- equal width menu items;
- menu items spread across the whole page width (not just crowd at the left side);
- dynamic (css rules should not rely on predefined number of items);
- drop-down second level with vertically aligned items;
- pure CSS (no JS!).

This seems to describe a perfect menu as i see it.

I have almost succeded making it using the beautiful `display: table-cell;` technique ( tags are omitted for simplicity):

```html
<ul>
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>
        Expandable ↓
        <ul>
            <li>Menu</li>
            <li>Menu item</li>
            <li>Menu item long</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;    
}

li:nth-child(even){
    background-color: lightblue;    
}

li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: lightskyblue;    
}

li ul { display: none; }

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

The only problem is that submenu items appear full-page width and partially outside the browser window, forcing a horizontal scrollbar to appear:

Gah! StackOverflow won't let me post images. Test it out live on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/9/

I can overcome this by adding `float: left; clear: both;` to `li:hover ul li`. But when i do, submenu items have different widths:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/10/

...or width `width: 15%;`: http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/12/

Both fixes are ugly and resolve neither the equal width issue nor the horizontal scrollbar issue.

**UPD** While brushing up this post i've found some solution of the scrollbar problem: set `li:hover ul` width to 0. But this forces to spectify the width of submenu items in an absolute value. :( See http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/13/

Also, this solution may suck hard when the last menu item is expanded. Depending on the screen width, it may still blow the page wider than the window: http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/15/

**Questions:**

1. How do i make submenu items appear same widths as their parent and without enabling the horizontal scrollbar?
2. Is there another CSS technique that allows creating a menu with ALL the prerequisites described in the beginning of the post?

I've found a lot of examples, but each of them either is non-stretching (floats items to the left) or non-dynamic (uses sizes taken from a predefined number of items, e. g. `width: 20%` for each of five first-level items or, even worse, uses absolute sizes!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the best way to do this, but here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6PTpd/17/

The funny thing about CSS is that even the masters are always finding new things that you can do with it. It's an amazing language in that way. Which is why I gave you that fiddle, so that you could learn what you were doing wrong (It was mainly the absolute positioning, BTW). BUT there are also some loopholes that you should be aware of.

So let me explain why you probably shouldn't use the code in that JSFiddle. The first problem is that it uses `display: none`. That's a problem because screen-readers don't read text that isn't displaying. (more on that over here: http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/)

The second problem is that it displays on hover. In a world where touch screens are becoming more and more prevalent, hover is no longer the best option.

You can still use it if you want to, just thought you should know about the drawbacks.

TL;DR: If screen-reader and touch screen support is an issue, then I would encourage you to search out another option.

Comment: The solution suggested by you ALREADY works on tablets! You just have to make the top-level expandable item non-clickable. :D

Comment: Ah, good. I'm glad. Nice design, by the way, those blues look quite nice together.

Comment: It works out of the box only for Android. For iOS, i had to use [this fix](http://niteodesign.com/web-design/iphone-ipad-ios-and-the-css-hover-event/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to make a perfect menu either using HTML and CSS coding, especially if you are using HTML5 & CSS3, and you can find a lot of examples by searching the internet.
The second easy way is by using programs which will make the coding easier for you like Sothink DHTML Menu, or http://css3menu.com